# Convert from absolute to relative path

Tags: java, linux, fedora, relative-path, absolute-path

I would like to convert this relative path
/home/cce2050/Music/part1/ints10000.dat
to its absolute path. Can anybody suggest me the path?

```
public static String[] split() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("/home/cce2050/Music/part1/ints10000.dat")));

    String line;

    String[] aList = new String[10000];

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        aList = line.split("\\s+");

    }

    return aList;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to convert a relative path to an absolute path, I would recommend using `File.getCanonicalPath()` You can see the docs on it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). Additionally, you can read a little more about relative and absolute path conversions [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-path).

So if you wanted to find the relative path, you could write something like:

```
String absolutePath = (new File("Your/Relative/Path")).getCanonicalPath()
```

That being said, let it be known that Unix System absolute file paths are referenced from the `/home` directory. The file path you specified may already be absolute

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you have a wrong understanding in what is relative/absolute path. 
Absolute path specifies path from the root **/** to the file while relative path specifies path from the current directory (position) to the specified file.

The path you have provided is an absolute path already.

Answer (score 0):

You have a miss a confusion between absolute and relative paths, so I think you are asking about this:

```
./Music/part1/ints10000.dat
```